# how can I open a file with ipython?

Tags: ipython

I could open my csv file by IDLE python 
It worked well

but I have to use pandas, so I try Ipython

Ipython can't find csv file saying that
"No such file or directory"

even though I type the exactly same code on Ipython

how can I solve this problem?

thank you very much

Comment: you can e.g. use absolute instead of relative paths.

Comment: Use pwd in ipython to see where you are. cd to change your current directory. Decide if you want to copy the file, change dir, or use absolute paths as @cel suggested.